# R - how to switch rows by row index

Tags: r, indexing, rows, col

Lets say I have a dataset with many columns and rows. Does R have the ability to reference rows so that I can switch rows like so?

```
df1[row:1] <- df1[row:2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a row index you like. Maybe use `order` to create one. Then apply it...

```
> df <- head(mtcars, 3)
> df
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1

> df[c(3,1,2), ]
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

> df[order(df$wt), ]
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question, but since your SO score is very low, I also assume that you are a beginner in R.
To index rows of a df in R, you can use the following syntax: `df_name[row_nr,]`

This means if you have the following df:

```
df1  <- head(ChickWeight)
df1

  weight Time Chick Diet
1     42    0     1    1
2     51    2     1    1
3     59    4     1    1
```

You can overwrite row 1 with the values from row 2, as follows:

```
df1[1,] <- df1[2,]


  weight Time Chick Diet
1     51    2     1    1
2     51    2     1    1
3     59    4     1    1
```

If you want to switch to rows 1 and 2, you need to use a helper / temporary variable:

```
tmp_row  <- df1[1,]
df1[1,]  <- df1[2,]
df1[2,]  <- tmp_row

  weight Time Chick Diet
1     51    2     1    1
2     42    0     1    1
3     59    4     1    1
```